# Blender 2.8 EVEE transparency in Alpha Blend mode

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

I know Blender 2.8 and EVEE is still in development, but I have strange transparency behavior while using Alpha Blend mode on texture. When I move view or camera textured object with Alpha blend mode just overlays whatever object is under it (first picture). [image] And if I change angle slightly (second picture) [image] it has normal transparency again. In alpha clip and alpha hashed blend modes transparency works properly no matter how i move the view. Is it some sorting issue withing blender?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug on unfinished experimental development software

Comment: You can post this as a bug (potentially) [here](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest)

Comment: No, Blender isn't finished yet, developers are aware of this. Bug reports are only open for reproducible crashes at the moment.